# Error logging in C#

Tags: c#, error-reporting, error-logging

I am making my switch from coding in C++ to C#.  I need to replace my C++ error logging/reporting macro system with something similar in C#.

In my C++ source I can write

LOGERR("Some error");
or
LOGERR("Error with inputs %s and %d", stringvar, intvar);

The macro & supporting library code then passes the (possibly varargs) formatted message into a database along with the source file, source line, user name, and time.  The same data is also stuffed into a data structure for later reporting to the user.

Does anybody have C# code snippets or pointers to examples that do this basic error reporting/logging?

**Edit:**  At the time I asked this question I was really new to .NET and was unaware of System.Diagnostics.Trace.  System.Diagnostics.Trace was what I needed at that time.  Since then I have used log4net on projects where the logging requirements were larger and more complex.  Just edit that 500 line XML configuration file and log4net will do everything you will ever need :)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Lots of log4net advocates here so I'm sure this will be ignored, but I'll add my own preference:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace
```

This includes listeners that listen for your `Trace()` methods, and then write to a log file/output window/event log, ones in the framework that are included are `DefaultTraceListener`, `TextWriterTraceListener` and the `EventLogTraceListener`. It allows you to specify levels (Warning,Error,Info) and categories.

[Trace class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx)
[Writing to the Event Log in a Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286060/what-do-i-need-to-change-to-alllow-my-iis7-asp-net-3-5-application-to-create-an/7848414#7848414)
[UdpTraceListener - write log4net compatible XML messages to a log viewer such as log2console](http://www.anotherchris.net/log4net/udptracelistener-a-udp-tracelistener-compatible-with-log4netlog4j/)

Comment: +1 Small addition, Trace is active if and only if you've compiled with the TRACE preprocessor symbol.

Comment: One thing to note with the TextWriterTraceListener is it doesn't do timestamps

Comment: You can override the `WriteLine()` method in the `TextWriterTraceListener` to achieve automatic time-stamping capability in the log file. See [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/customnettracelisteners.aspx), section 6.

Comment: Nice tip @user7116. I want to mention that compiling with Trace predecessor will decrease performance; and you can enable it in _"Project Properties>Build>Define TRACE constant"_ .

Answer (score 41):

I would highly recommend looking at [log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/). This [post](https://mitchwheat.com/2007/04/29/log4net-net-logging-tool/) covers the majority of what you need to get started.

Comment: "At the start of each class declare a logger instance as follows..." You lost me there. :-)

Answer (score 14):

Another good logging library is [NLog](http://www.nlog-project.org/), which can log to a lot of different places, such as files, databases, event logger etc.

Answer (score 14):

I use [The Object Guy's Logging Framework](http://www.theobjectguy.com/dotnetlog)--as do most people who try it. This guy has some interesting [comments](http://blog.rantingsandravings.com/2009/02/logging-frameworks.html) about it.

Answer (score 11):

[Enterprise Library](http://www.codeplex.com/entlib) is a solid alternative to [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) and it offers a bunch of other capabilities as well (caching, exception handling, validation, etc...).  I use it on just about every project I build.

Highly recommended.

Comment: EL can even send out emails as part of the logging. Very handy when reporting prod errors.

Answer (score 5):

Even though I personally hate it, [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) seems to be the de facto standard for C# logging.  Sample usage:

```
log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
log.Error(“Some error”);
log.ErrorFormat("Error with inputs {0} and {1}", stringvar, intvar);
```

Comment: It gets the job done, but I hate the documentation and am resentful for having spent many hours tinkering with config files and basically flying blind until I could get relatively simple things working the way I wanted them to.

Comment: I've used log4net and appreciate it's a powerful tool (and NHibernate and others use it). But I'm curious why people don't like using the .NET 2.0 inbuilt tracing? With the different type of listeners and a few tools it seems a lot less messy than log4net, which is a java port.

Comment: Can hear you about the documentation (somewhat). Which is why looking at the code of decent open source projects that utilize it is a huge time saver. After that, it's by far my favorite logging utility.

Comment: @Ted: a nice idea - Would you care to recommend a couple of projects to look at to learn about logging?

Answer (score 5):

As I said in another thread, we've been using [The Object Guy's Logging Framework](http://www.theobjectguy.com/dotnetlog) in multiple production apps for several years. It's super easy to use and extend.

Answer (score 3):

[Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) is a rather comprehensive logging framework that will allow you to log to different levels (Debug, Error, Fatal) and output these log statements to may different places (rolling file, web service, windows errors)

I am able to easily log anywhere by creating an instance of the logger

```
private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof([Class Name]));
```

and then logging the error.

```
_log.Error("Error messsage", ex);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Serilog](http://serilog.net) is late to the party here, but brings some interesting options to the table. It looks much like classical text-based loggers to use:

```
Log.Information("Hello, {0}", username);
```

But, unlike earlier frameworks, it only renders the message and arguments into a string when writing text, e.g. to a file or the console.

The idea is that if you're using a 'NoSQL'-style data store for logs, you can record events like:

```
{
    Timestamp: "2014-02-....",
    Message: "Hello, nblumhardt",
    Properties:
    {
        "0": "nblumhardt"
    }
}
```

The .NET format string syntax is extended so you can write the above example as:

```
Log.Information("Hello, {Name}", username);
```

In this case the property will be called `Name` (rather than `0`), making querying and correlation easier.

There are already a few good options for storage. MongoDB and Azure Table Storage seem to be quite popular for DIY. I originally built Serilog (though it is a community project) and I'm now working on a product called [Seq](http://getseq.net), which provides storage and querying of these kinds of structured log events.

Answer (score 2):

You can use built in .NET logging.  Look into TraceSource and TraceListeners, they can be configured in the .config file.

Answer (score 1):

Ditto for log4net. I'm adding my two bits because for actual use, it makes sense to look at some open source implementations to see real world code samples with some handy additions. For log4net, I'd suggest off the top of my head looking at [subtext](http://subtextproject.com/). Particularly take a look at the application start and assemblyinfo bits.

Answer (score 1):

Further to the couple of comments realting to the use of the System.Diagnostics methods for logging, I would also like to point out that the [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) tool is very neat for checking debug output when needed - unless you require it, there is no need for the apps to produce a log file, you just launch DebugView as and when needed.

Answer (score 1):

The built in tracing in System.Diagnostics is fine in the .NET Framework and I use it on many applications.  However, one of the primary reasons I still use log4net is that the built in .NET Framework tracing lacks many of the useful full featured appenders that log4net already supplies built in.

For instance there really isn't a good rolling file trace listener defined in the .NET Framework other than the one in a VB.NET dll which really is not all that full featured.

Depending on your development environment I would recommend using log4net unless 3rd party tools are not available, then I'd say use the System.Diagnostics tracing classes.  If you really need a better appender/tracelistener you can always implement it yourself.

For instance many of our customers require that we do not use open source libraries when installed on their corporate machines, so in that case the .NET Framework tracing classes are a perfect fit.

Additionally - http://www.postsharp.org/ is an AOP library I'm looking into that may also assist in logging as demonstrated here on code project:http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/log4postsharp-intro.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

[ExceptionLess](https://exceptionless.com/) is one of the easiest nuget package available to use for logging. Its an [open source](https://github.com/exceptionless/Exceptionless) project. It automatically takes care of unhandled exception, and options for [manually logs](https://github.com/exceptionless/Exceptionless.Net/wiki/Sending-Events) are available. You can log to online or [self host](https://github.com/exceptionless/Exceptionless/wiki/Self-Hosting) on local server.

Comment: I work on the Exceptionless project and would be more than happy to answer any questions. We have logging targets for all of the major logging frameworks so you can get a lot of value right out of the box by using Exceptionless (free log messages + unhandled exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

Log4Net, as others have said, is fairly common and similar to Log4j which will help you if you ever do any Java.

You also have the option of using the Logging Application Block http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/GetStartedLoggingBlock.aspx