# What do I need to change to allow my IIS7 ASP.Net 3.5 application to create an event source and log events to Windows EventLog?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, iis-7, permissions, event-log

ASP.Net 3.5 running under IIS 7 doesn't seem to allow this out of the box.

```
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists("MyAppLog"))
            EventLog.CreateEventSource("MyAppLog", "Application");

        EventLog myLog = new EventLog();
        myLog.Source = "MyAppLog";
        myLog.WriteEntry("Message");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Security.SecurityException when writing to Event Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274018/system-security-securityexception-when-writing-to-event-log)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is part of windows security since windows 2003.

You need to create an entry in the registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application Make sure that network service or the account you impersonate has permission to this registry key.

@CheGueVerra's link: [Requested Registry Access Is Not Allowed](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=329291)

Comment: Link is no longer working

Answer (score 42):

I've copied this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587453/log4net-eventlogappender-does-not-work-for-asp-net-2-0-website) (the question was Log4Net but the answer still applies). The technet link misses a vital step.

#### Create a registry key

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\MY-AWESOME-APP`

#### Create a string value inside this

Name it `EventMessageFile`, set its value to

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\EventLogMessages.dll

That path appears to work in both 64 bit and 32 bit environments.

With this technique you don't need to set permissions in the registry, and once the key above is created it should just work.

**Alternatively**
If you don't have a large server farm but just a small "web garden" you could run a console application on each server that creates the event log source using [`EventLog.CreateEventSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zbwd3s3.aspx), make sure the console application is run by an administrator.

Comment: Since you mentioned log4net, here is the link to eventlogappender troubleshoot. https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#trouble-EventLog  . There is official ms link there on how to create event source. It prudent to note that this approach is not recommended for production use though.

Answer (score 6):

Right click the application and choose "Run as Administrator"