# Windows EventLog Permissions

Tags: asp.net, event-log

What permissions do I need to give a User for them to be able to write to the Windows EventLog? I have an ASP.NET application that needs to impersonate a user and that impersonated user must be able to write the event log

Comment: Write or create? Writing to the log with a unique source requires write access to registry keys (the source has an existence in the registry).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286060/what-do-i-need-to-change-to-alllow-my-iis7-asp-net-3-5-application-to-create-an

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an Event Log source you need to be an administrator, otherwise you should be able to write to it without elevated privileges.

Maybe take a look at [this article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN docs on Event Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363654(VS.85).aspx) (Win32) do not mention any required privileges.

Regardless, I'm not sure I understand why you need to write to the log using the impersonation token. You can still impersonate, but also write to the log with a different (admin) account, if that's necessary.