# EventLogAppender - How to stop errors being logged into application Event log

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I am  using log4net – EventLogAppender to log the application errors to a custom log.  This happens, but the errors are also logged in Application log. Since I have my own custom event log say myLog, is it possible to stop the errors being logged into default log Application?

```xml
<log4net debug="true">
  <appender name="sendAlertAppender" type="sendAlertAppender.MultiThresholdNotifyingAppender,sendAlertAppender">      
    <LevelThreshold  value="ERROR"/>      
  <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender"/>
  </appender>

  <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
    <param name="LogName" value="xxxWebLogs" />
    <param name="ApplicationName" value="xxx" />
    <eventId value="5" />
    <eventCategory value="10" />
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
      <levelMin value="INFO" />
      <levelMax value="FATAL" />        
    </filter>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <priority value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="sendAlertAppender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender"/>
  </root>
</log4net>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show your current log4net config?

Comment: if i understand correctly, you are asking how to log to the event log without logging to the event log.  is that correct?  if so, i think it's an absurd question.

Comment: @Garret pls see the log4net.config settings.

Comment: @Dave My question is ,i have my own eventlog file and errors are logging there. By default the errors will go to application log,i want to stop that.

Comment: Based on your configuration, the `LogName` parameter should be setting the Event log location.  Is it not working that way?

Comment: I am not sure whether i am explaining my problem in a right way. All the errors are getting logged in "xxxWebLogs" and it works fine. In addition it also logs the error in "Application" log[the default one].So i want to stop that.

Comment: @Garret the errors are logged into both PortalWeblogs and also Application log. Since i am logging in custom event viewer ,i don't want that in Application log.

Comment: @Vani - that's the clarification i wanted.  i was confused by you saying you have your own event viewer.  you were talking about having your own event log.

Comment: @Dave..  I misused the words..  i am talking abt the own event log..

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure what your issue is, but looking at the configuration I believe you need to change the `LogName` setting:

```
<param name="LogName" value="PortalWebLogs" />
```

If this doesn't work, it could be a permissions issue.  See here for more information:

[log4Net EventlogAppender does not work for Asp.Net 2.0 WebSite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587453/log4net-eventlogappender-does-not-work-for-asp-net-2-0-website)

Comment: The errors are logged into both PortalWeblogs and also Application log. Since i am logging in custom eventlog "PortalWeblogs"  ,i don't want that in Application log.Pls see the attached  image.

Comment: What's in the sendAlertAppender code?  Is that possibly logging to the event log as well?

Comment: sendAlertAppender is extension of log4net for sending the alert emails.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done much with using the event log appender, so i'm not really sure.  here's another question talking about it and in the answer, it shows using a logName element with a value attribute instead of a param element.  might be worth trying that.

[Configuring a custom event log for log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416800/configuring-a-custom-event-log-for-log4net)